Is it possible to hide part of a character in Flame?
In Godot, I was able to hide part of a character using a feature called Y Sort. How can I achieve this in Flutter Flame? It doesn’t have to be Y Sort specifically; any method that can achieve this functionality would be fine.
Y Sort Example: How Does Y Sort Allow Partial Overlap with Objects in Godot?
